# Three.js site displays black lines, caught problem only in one computer after trying in several different devices

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I created a portfolio website with Threejs. After I published it, I tried accessing it in different browsers and devices and it worked fine.

I shared it with a few friends for feedback, and only one has gotten back to me with this strange shadow texture appearing throughout the canvas. See screenshot below:

[image: 1]

He tried in different browsers, in the same device, and got the same result.

This is how it is supposed to look like, and how it looks everywhere I checked. See below:

[image: 2]

Anyone has any idea why could this be?

I would like to make the site as compatible as possible.

Perhaps it is an issue with the rendered, or one of the tonemappings. I am using THREE.WebGLRenderer. Maybe it isn't supported on his device which is a microsoft surfaces laptop

Code below:

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
import "./Three.css";
import { gsap } from 'gsap/all';
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';
import {RGBELoader} from "three/examples/jsm/loaders/RGBELoader";
//Importing materials
import materials from './Materials';

window.onload = function(){

let camera, scene, renderer, spotLight, hemiLight;

let previousShadowMap = false;

// // ref for lumens: http://www.power-sure.com/lumens.htm
//   '110000 lm (1000W)': 110000,
//   '3500 lm (300W)': 3500,
//   '1700 lm (100W)': 1700,
//   '800 lm (60W)': 800,
//   '400 lm (40W)': 400,
//   '180 lm (25W)': 180,
//   '20 lm (4W)': 20,
//   'Off': 0


// // ref for solar irradiances: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lux
//   '0.0001 lx (Moonless Night)': 0.0001,
//   '0.002 lx (Night Airglow)': 0.002,
//   '0.5 lx (Full Moon)': 0.5,
//   '3.4 lx (City Twilight)': 3.4,
//   '50 lx (Living Room)': 50,
//   '100 lx (Very Overcast)': 100,
//   '350 lx (Office Room)': 350,
//   '400 lx (Sunrise/Sunset)': 400,
//   '1000 lx (Overcast)': 1000,
//   '18000 lx (Daylight)': 18000,
//   '50000 lx (Direct Sun)': 50000


init();
animate();

function init() {
scene = new THREE.Scene();

const hdrTextureURL = new URL("../img/studio.hdr", import.meta.url);
const loadingManager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, .01, 20 );

renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({alpha: false, antialias: true});
renderer.physicallyCorrectLights = true;
renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.VSMShadowMap;
renderer.outputEncoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
renderer.toneMapping = THREE.ReinhardToneMapping;
renderer.toneMappingExposure = .5;
renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

window.addEventListener("resize", onWindowResize, false);

function onWindowResize(){
  let width = window.innerWidth;
  let height = window.innerHeight;
  camera.aspect = width / height;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  renderer.setSize(width, height);
}

function moveCamera (x, y, z) {
  gsap.to(camera.position,    {
    x,
    y, 
    z, 
    duration: 5
});}

function rotateCamera (x, y, z){
gsap.to(camera.rotation, {
  x,
  y,
  z,
  duration: 5
});}

document.getElementById("work").addEventListener("click", function(){
  moveCamera(1.705767645472689, .92, 0.8242832549970878);
  rotateCamera(0, -1.8, 0);
});
  document.getElementById("rs").addEventListener("click", function(){
    moveCamera(-.2, 1.500, 4);
    rotateCamera(-.2, 0, 0);
});
document.getElementById("about").addEventListener("click", function(){
  moveCamera(-.200, 1.700, 0);
  rotateCamera(0, 0, 0);
  function waitForElm(selector) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        if (document.querySelector(selector)) {
            return resolve(document.querySelector(selector));
        }
        const observer = new MutationObserver(mutations => {
            if (document.querySelector(selector)) {
                resolve(document.querySelector(selector));
                observer.disconnect();
            }
        });
        observer.observe(document.body, {
            childList: true,
            subtree: true
        });
    });
  }
  waitForElm('.aboutDiv').then((elm) => {
    elm.style.opacity= 1;
  });
});
document.getElementById("designwork").addEventListener("click", function(){
  moveCamera(-1, 1.300, 1.5);
  rotateCamera(0, 1.5, 0);
});

camera.position.set(-.2, 1.500, 4);
rotateCamera(-.1,0,0);

// Loading models

const loader = new GLTFLoader(loadingManager);

loader.load( './gltf/screen.glb', function ( gltf ) {           
  gltf.scene.traverse((o) => {
    if (o.isMesh) o.material = materials[3];
  });
  gltf.scene.traverse((o) => {
    if (o.isMesh) {
    o.castShadow = true;
    o.receiveShadow = true;
    }
  });
  scene.add( gltf.scene );
    },
);

loader.load( './gltf/shelf.glb', function ( gltf ) {    
  gltf.scene.traverse((o) => {
    if (o.isMesh) o.material = materials[5];
  });       
  gltf.scene.traverse((o) => {
    if (o.isMesh) {
    o.castShadow = true;
    o.receiveShadow = true;
    }
  });
  scene.add( gltf.scene );
    },
);

loader.load( './gltf/archArt.glb', function ( gltf ) {          
  gltf.scene.traverse((o) => {
    if (o.isMesh) o.material = materials[9];
  });
  gltf.scene.traverse((o) => {
    if (o.isMesh) {
    o.castShadow = true;
    o.receiveShadow = true;
    }
  });
  scene.add( gltf.scene );
    },
);

loader.load( './gltf/la.glb', function ( gltf ) {           
  gltf.scene.traverse((o) => {
    if (o.isMesh) o.material = materials[8];
  });
  gltf.scene.traverse((o) => {
    if (o.isMesh) {
    o.castShadow = true;
    o.receiveShadow = true;
    }
  });
  scene.add( gltf.scene );
    },
);

loader.load( './gltf/marbella.glb', function ( gltf ) {         
  gltf.scene.traverse((o) => {
    if (o.isMesh) o.material = materials[7];
  });
  gltf.scene.traverse((o) => {
    if (o.isMesh) {
    o.castShadow = true;
    o.receiveShadow = true;
    }
  });
  scene.add( gltf.scene );
    },
);

loader.load( './gltf/wall.glb', function ( gltf ) {         
  gltf.scene.traverse((o) => {
    if (o.isMesh) o.material = materials[1];
  });
  gltf.scene.traverse((o) => {
    if (o.isMesh) {
    o.castShadow = true;
    o.receiveShadow = true;
    }
  });
  scene.add( gltf.scene );
    },
);

loader.load( './gltf/white.glb', function ( gltf ) {            
  const newMat = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
    roughness: 1,
    metalness: 0,
    color: 0xf1f0ea,
  })
  gltf.scene.traverse((o) => {
    if (o.isMesh) o.material = newMat;
  });
  gltf.scene.traverse((x) => {
    if (x.isMesh) {
    x.castShadow = true;
    x.receiveShadow = true;
    x.geometry.computeVertexNormals();
    }
  });
  scene.add( gltf.scene );
    },
);  

loader.load( './gltf/arch.glb', function ( gltf ) {     
  const newMat = new THREE.MeshPhysicalMaterial({
    roughness: .5,
    metalness: .2,
    color: 0xb0b0a9,
    clearcoat: 1,
    clearcoatRoughness: .2,
  })    
  gltf.scene.traverse((o) => {
    if (o.isMesh) o.material = newMat;
  });
  gltf.scene.traverse((x) => {
    if (x.isMesh) {
    x.castShadow = true;
    x.receiveShadow = true;
    x.geometry.computeVertexNormals();
    }
  });
  scene.add( gltf.scene );
    },
);  

loader.load( './gltf/black.glb', function ( gltf ) {            
  const newMat = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
    roughness: 1,
    metalness:0.8,
    color: 0x0e0e10,
  })
  gltf.scene.traverse((o) => {
    if (o.isMesh) o.material = newMat;
  });
  gltf.scene.traverse((x) => {
    if (x.isMesh) {
    x.castShadow = true;
    x.receiveShadow = true;
    x.geometry.computeVertexNormals();
    }
  });
  scene.add( gltf.scene );
    },
);  

loader.load( './gltf/floor.glb', function ( gltf ) {            
  gltf.scene.traverse((o) => {
    if (o.isMesh) {
      o.material = materials[0];
  }
  });
  gltf.scene.traverse((o) => {
    if (o.isMesh) {
    o.castShadow = true;
    o.receiveShadow = true;
    }
  });
  scene.add( gltf.scene );
    },
);  

loader.load( './gltf/table.glb', function ( gltf ) {        
  gltf.scene.traverse((o) => {
    if (o.isMesh) o.material = materials[6];
  });
  gltf.scene.traverse((x) => {
    if (x.isMesh) {
    x.castShadow = true;
    x.receiveShadow = true;
    }
  });
    scene.add( gltf.scene );
    },
);   

loader.load( './gltf/table2.glb', function ( gltf ) {       
  // materials[4].map.repeat.set(  2, 8  );
  // materials[4].bumpMap.repeat.set(  2, 8  );
  // materials[4].map.rotation =(Math.PI);
  // materials[4].bumpMap.rotation =(Math.PI);
  gltf.scene.traverse((o) => {
    if (o.isMesh) o.material = materials[4];
  });
  gltf.scene.traverse((x) => {
    if (x.isMesh) {
    x.castShadow = true;
    x.receiveShadow = true;
    x.geometry.computeVertexNormals();
    }
  });
    scene.add( gltf.scene );
    },
);  

loader.load( './gltf/metal.glb', function ( gltf ) {        
  const newMat = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
    roughness: .2,
    metalness: .8,
    transparent: false,
    color: 0x2b2b2c ,
  })
  gltf.scene.traverse((o) => {
    if (o.isMesh) o.material = newMat;
  });
  gltf.scene.traverse((x) => {
    if (x.isMesh) {
    x.castShadow = true;
    x.receiveShadow = true;
    x.geometry.computeVertexNormals();
    }
  });
    scene.add( gltf.scene );
    },
);

loader.load( './gltf/flooredge.glb', function ( gltf ) {        
  gltf.scene.traverse((o) => {
    if (o.isMesh) o.material = materials[2];
  });
  gltf.scene.traverse((x) => {
    if (x.isMesh) {
    x.castShadow = true;
    x.receiveShadow = true;
    x.geometry.computeVertexNormals();
    }
  });
    scene.add( gltf.scene );
    },
);

const loaderHDR = new RGBELoader(loadingManager);
loaderHDR.load(hdrTextureURL, function(texture){
  texture.mapping = THREE.EquirectangularReflectionMapping;
  scene.background = texture;
});

//  Load Light

const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xffffff, .6 );
scene.add( ambientLight );

hemiLight = new THREE.HemisphereLight(
  0xffeeb1, // bright sky color
  0x000000, // dim ground color
  1 // intensity
);
scene.add( hemiLight );
            
const directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xfff5b6, 10 );
directionalLight.position.set( 5.000, 6.000, -1.00 );
directionalLight.shadow.bias = -0.001;
directionalLight.target.position.set(0, 0, 0);
directionalLight.shadow.mapSize = new THREE.Vector2(1024 * 2, 1024 * 2);
const frustumSize = 15;
directionalLight.shadow.camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(-frustumSize / 2, frustumSize / 2, frustumSize/2 , -frustumSize/2 , .100, 10.000);
directionalLight.shadow.camera.far = 20.000;

directionalLight.castShadow = true;
scene.add( directionalLight );  

spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffa95c, 3000);
spotLight.position.set( -1.000, 3.400, 0 );
spotLight.target.position.set(0, 0, -1.000);
spotLight.angle = Math.PI/2.5;
spotLight.penumbra = .5;
spotLight.power = 40;
spotLight.decay = 1;
spotLight.shadow.bias = -0.001;
spotLight.shadow.mapSize = new THREE.Vector2(1024 * 2, 1024 * 2);
spotLight.shadow.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10 );
spotLight.castShadow = true;
scene.add(spotLight);

for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  const light = spotLight.clone();
  light.position.set(-2, 3.4, i);
  light.target.position.set(-2, 0, 0);
  scene.add(light);
}
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  const light = spotLight.clone();
  light.position.set(2, 3.4, i);
  light.target.position.set(2, 0, 0);
  scene.add(light);
}


let progressBar, progressContainer;

progressBar = document.getElementById("progress")
progressContainer = document.querySelector(".progress-bar-container")
loadingManager.onProgress = function(url, loaded, total){
  progressBar.value = (loaded/ total)*100;
}
loadingManager.onLoad = function() {
  progressContainer.style.display = "none";
}

}

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame( animate );
  render();
}

function render() {
  renderer.toneMappingExposure = Math.pow( 0.9, 5.0 ); // to allow for very bright scenes.
  renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;

  if ( true !== previousShadowMap ) {
    for (let i = 0; i < materials.length; i++) {
      materials[i].needsUpdate = true;
    }
    previousShadowMap = true;
  }
}
}
```

Comment: Please post code not images.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Does the glitch go away if your are using the default shadow map type and not `THREE.VSMShadowMap`?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments. I looked into the webGL Renderer parameters and figured out the issue.

It has to do with the precision shader parameter.

From the Threejs documentation:

precision - Shader precision. Can be "highp", "mediump" or "lowp". Defaults to "highp" if supported by the device.

Some devices, if not specified in the WebGL class, will set it to lowp. Specifying high hp fixed the issue.